# Where can i find the surface area and the number of premises for all UK districts?

Tags: data-request, government, geospatial, uk, real-estate

I am looking for the surface area, and the number of premises for each UK district. The districts should be listed with their [ONS codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ONS_coding_system).

---

Rationale: I am trying to process and aggregate [Ofcom data for mobile network coverage](http://stakeholders.ofcom.org.uk/binaries/research/infrastructure/2014/Mobile_local_authority.csv) in the UK. For the districts of the UK, they list

- the ratio of the surface area with signal
- the ratio of premises with signal

for each of UK's four major mobile network operators (Vodafone, O2, Three, EE). Unfortunately, Ofcom doesn't mention the totals (or at least i haven't found them).

---

Note: The Ofcom data is actually not distributed across UK *districts* throughout. Instead, it uses various levels of non-overlapping administrative units:

- All districts of Wales, Scotland and Northern Ireland
- All 'Unitary Authorities' in England
- All metropolitan districts in England
- All counties in England with county councils ('shires')
- Greater London is a single row.

Luckily they are all listed with their administrative ONS codes (with the exception of greater London which is listed with an extra code '00-London'), so it should be straightforward to reproduce the Ofcom aggregation.

Comment: I'd start looking here : http://data.gov.uk/data/search

Comment: I had searched there without success. Maybe i am using the wrong search terms? E.g. various combinations of 'surface', 'area', 'premises', 'districts' result in a lot of unrelated hits.

Comment: It might be an issue with synonyms, if they have it.  Eg, searching for 'rain fall' when they have data for 'precipitation'.

Comment: You appear to be referring to first level administrative divisions of the UK. For surface area, I presume you mean total land area. What do you mean by premises (e.g., number housing units)?

Comment: According to the Ofcom report (http://stakeholders.ofcom.org.uk/market-data-research/market-data/infrastructure/infrastructure-2014/) they use "postal delivery points" to calculate "premises coverage" (see page 177). And i guess 'total land area' is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I want to say I am not an expert at using UK Ordnance Survey data.

As Nils pointed out, page 177 in this wifi/broadband coverage report for 2014 makes references to the number of premises (buildings). The report refers to the data source as coming from the UK Ordnance Survey. I looked at the sample datasets, and they do contain building addresses per city/county equivalent.

There are a number of licensing options. Some are free. As far as understanding the licensing of this dataset, I would start here:

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/licensing/using-creating-data-with-os-products/index.html

On the Office of National Statistics (ONS) I searched for 'land area'. The resulting list was fairly long. I did find some CSV/Excel datasets that contained land area on at least a county equivalent.

http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/datasets-and-tables/index.html?pageSize=50&sortBy=none&sortDirection=none&newquery=land+area&content-type=Reference+table&content-type=Dataset